# Is there a contradiction between Romans 2:10 & Romans 2:11?

Tags: contradiction, romans

Romans 2:10(KJV)

> 10 But glory, honour, and peace, to every man that worketh good, to the Jew first, and also to the Gentile:  11 For there is no respect of persons with God.

The (NKJV) says for there is no partiality with God,but it says to the Jew first

Romans 3:1(KJV)

> 1 What advantage then hath the Jew?  or what profit is there of circumcision?  2 Much every way:  chiefly, because that unto them were committed the oracles of God

Comment: search and compare all verses of "jew firist". It is for Israel's primacy in everything due to their national election. (Rom 9:2-5) this does not affect moral spiritual judgment or justice.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my own analysis of Romans 2:10:

[image]

The problem here is the conjunction "τε". As far as I can tell, the KJV leaves it out, but to do so makes utter nonsense of the next verse.

I think the two verses Romans 2:10-11 should read:

> Praise and honour and peace to everyone. To the one who does good, whether to Jew first, or to Greek. For there is no favouritism with God.

If you were to ask me why the KJV ignored the conjunction, I can only say: even though there is no partiality with God, there is with men. The Jews as God's "chosen people" is a compelling reason to see in the text something that just isn't there, even though it makes a mockery of the message.

Comment: What exactly is EPV?

Comment: @Tauri The first sentence of my answer says, "*Here is my own analysis of Romans 2:10*". EPV is **E**negue's **P**ersonal **V**ersion. I figure, given time, I will analyse the entire Bible. I have developed a program, from which the screen shot was taken, that utilises all the public domain resources available to me. I have no formal credentials regarding Greek or Hebrew, only a familiarity with the languages that comes from my analyses.